# Wicket: "Component-targetted feedback message was left unrendered" even though the FeedbackPanel is on the page

Tags: java, wicket

I'm using apache wicket 1.4.22.  I've got an error which indicates that a feedback panel is missing from my page.  However, I have added it - so why is the feedback not showing?

> Component-targetted feedback message was left unrendered. This could be because you are missing a FeedbackPanel on the page.  Message: [FeedbackMessage message = "Problem retrieving transactions for subscription 2971", reporter = 4, level = ERROR]

Here's an extract of the page constructor:

```
public class SubDetailPage extends AbstractCCPage {

public SubDetailPage(final CCSubscription sub) {

    if(sub.getTransactions()==null || sub.getTransactions().isEmpty())  
        error("Problem retrieving transactions for subscription "+sub.getSubscriptionId());
```

And here's the super class:

```
public abstract class AbstractCCPage extends WebPage {

protected final FeedbackPanel feedbackPanel;

public AbstractCCPage() {

    feedbackPanel = new FeedbackPanel("info-panel");
    feedbackPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(feedbackPanel);
```

I've used feedback panels before.  They work fine.  What am I doing wrong here?  I just can't see it.

A little bit of debugging shows that the feedback message was added to the list:

```
Session.get().getFeedbackMessages();
```

shows that the message is in there.

And the page rendered does indeed have an (empty) info-panel:

```
<div id="info_panel45" class="info-panel"> </div>
```

---edit----

some more debugging: if I put the following line in the AbstractCCPage constructor, it works:

```
error("hello world");
```

but if I put the same line in the SubDetailPage constructor, it doesn't - even though both constructors are being called.

Comment: no ajax on the page at all.

Comment: Do you call `super()` in your constructor in `SubDetailPage`?

Comment: I don't explicitly call super() - but it should be implicit.  But I've now tried adding a call to super(), and I still have the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  Right at the end of the AbstractCCPage I had the following entry:

```
add(new PageView("componentTree", this));
```

This was to add a breakdown the page structure at debug level so we can see the tree on the page.

Removing this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be caused by a redirect to your page:

Wicket redirects to your page instance without actually rendering the page, but the Feedback message is already added.

Try moving the call to #error() to #onBeforeRender().